# AWS EB with python 3.6 errors and uses python 2.7

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

How do I get the aWS EB instance to use the python 3 version that is already installed on the instance?
I can't get a new environment running with Python 3.6 running Django 2.1+.

**Local (not in virtual env):**

```
which python -> /usr/local/bin/python
python -V -> Python 2.7.15
which python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 -V -> Python 3.6.5
which pip -> /usr/local/bin/pip
pip -V -> pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`
which pip3 -> /usr/local/bin/pip3
pip3 -V -> pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

**Local in virtualenv `mstFirst`**:

```
which python -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/python
which python3 -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/python
python -V -> Python 3.6.5
python3 -V -> Python 3.6.5
which pip -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/pip
which pip3 -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/pip3
pip -V -> pip 18.0 from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
pip3 -V -> pip 18.0 from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
aws --version -> aws-cli/1.16.9 Python/3.6.5 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.11.9
eb --version -> EB CLI 3.14.4 (Python 3.6.5)
eb -list -> * mst-p3
eb -config ->
  ApplicationName: mst
  DateUpdated: 2018-09-07 02:15:51+00:00
  EnvironmentName: mst-p3
  PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.3
  settings: …
```

**Files**:

".elasticbeanstalk/config.yml"

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: mst-p3
environment-defaults:
  mst-p3: …
global:
  application_name: mst
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.3 running Python 3.6
  default_region: us-east-1
  workspace_type: Application
…
```

".ebextensions/01_packages.config"

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    python36: []
    python36-devel: []
    postgresql93: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    mod24_ssl : []

commands:
  pip_upgrade:
    command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
    ignoreErrors: false
```

Error when trying `eb deploy`, which points to wrong python version (2.7) while trying to run `pip install -r requirements.py`:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-jt3_s4in/slugger/
2018-09-07 03:28:35,315 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
    install_dependencies()
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
    check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

**Remote Instance ssh (`eb ssh`)**:

```
pyhthon -V -> Python 2.7.14
pyhthon3 -V -> Python 3.6.5
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Replacing the environment AMI with a current version and rebuilding per https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157777/1234721 , but the environment errors with an AMI of "ami-0ff8a91507f77f867" for "Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type"
- trying to hook into the YAML config to switch the python versions
- re-init using `eb init`

Comment: And what are `/opt/python/run/venv/bin/{python,pip} -V`, resp.?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I narrowed it down to the Python 2 `futures` library, but ever after scrubbing this from my requirements file the issue persists on new instance creation.

Comment: Nope.  I switched to EC2 with an ubuntu image.   Not terribly hard, but nginx/gunicorn gave me a good fight.